Blazor issue with connecting javascript code to c# - heap is currently locked
I am quite new to blazor/ web tech, not a proper c# programmer either. I have an issue with connecting my javascript  code to the c# methods. I read the documenation etc and tried few different ways but cannot get it work. I get this errror
Loaded 8.52 MB resources from cache
Debugging hotkey: Shift+Alt+D (when application has focus)
Uncaught Error Error: Assertion failed - heap is currently locked
    at Tt (localhost꞉44317/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:47036)
    at invokeDotNetFromJS (localhost꞉44317/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:45338)
    at invokeDotNetMethod (localhost꞉44317/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3485)
    at invokeDotNetStaticMethod (localhost꞉44317/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3241)
    at e.invokeMethod (localhost꞉44317/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:1980)
    at createPostcodeFromCoordinates (<eval>/VM46947987:254:29)
    at <anonymous> (<eval>/VM46947987:6:29)

javascript side
 function createPostcodeFromCoordinates(longitude, latitude) {

    var result = DotNet.invokeMethod('cLib', 'createPostcodeFromCoordinates', longitude, latitude);
//     var postcode = this.dotNetReference.invokeMethod("createPostcodeFromCoordinates");
    // DotNet.invokeMethod('cSharpLibraries', 'createPostcodeFromCoordinates', longitude, latitude)
    //     .then(result => {
    //         console.log(result);
    //     });

C#
public static string CreatePostcodeFromCoordinates(string longitude, string latitude)
{

// Many lines of logic...

  return result;
}

Any ideas how I can fix it? This error message above with Uncaught Error Error: Assertion failed - heap is currently locked
is probably the best I managed. I was getting some other more weird messages but I think this is better!  I don't need anything async but happy to have it. Trying to keep the call as simple as possible. Plus the debugger is not working in Visual studio which may have helped to understand what goes wrong.
Thanks very much!

The message "heap is currently locked" indicates that the code may be trying to access the resource while it is already in use.
Using async may help solve this problem, so you should use invokeMethodAsync instead of invokeMethod.
Try changing the line:
var result = DotNet.invokeMethod('cLib', 'createPostcodeFromCoordinates', longitude, latitude);

to
var result = await DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('cLib', 'createPostcodeFromCoordinates', longitude, latitude);


Thank you! Now i get :Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules. Then i removed the await and i get "Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: L is not defined" Not sure about that, cannot see anything called L in my code. Any other ideas? Thanks

The "await is only valid in async functions" error means that the function needs to be declared as async to use await. You could try changing your JavaScript function declaration to:
async function createPostcodeFromCoordinates etc.
As for the "Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined" error, this might be due to a typo or an undefined variable in your JavaScript code.
I recommend checking your code to see if there are any places where L.

I managed to resolve the issue i had with the debugger. I now get some more info . There is no loaded assembly with the name 'clib'.\n   at Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetDispatcher.GetRequiredLoadedAssembly(AssemblyKey assemblyKey)\n**    So looks like the .net code is not visible? Inside program,.cs i have the c# like:
[JSInvokable]
public static string CreatePostcodeFromCoordinates(string longitude, string latitude)
{

I had my c# code in another file but i said lets make sure it;s loaded just in case. Do i need to modify anything else to pick the C# code up? like the .csproj.,  Thank you!

Ok last update. So i renamed the clib (first param) to be the actual  project name BlazorAppWebAssemblyMap'. Now i get this error Error: System.ArgumentException: The assembly 'BlazorAppWebAssemblyMap' does not contain a public invokable method with [JSInvokableAttribute("createPostcodeFromCoordinates")]. I just want to call some c# from javascript. it looks as if clib is not loaded but all looks fine plus is included in the program.cs file. Thank you again. Panos

It seems Blazor WebAssembly can't find your C# method due to a definition issue. Try these steps:
1.Ensure it’s public static with [JSInvokable("createPostcodeFromCoordinates")].
2.In JavaScript, use the exact project name from .csproj, e.g., DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('BlazorAppWebAssemblyMap', 'createPostcodeFromCoordinates', longitude, latitude);
3.If the C# code is in a separate project, make sure it's referenced in the Blazor WebAssembly project.
If issues persist, try clearing your cache.
